# How can I have a custom variable in my Jenkins build-description?

Tags: jenkins

My code is currently setting the Jenkins currentBuild-description like this:

```
post {
  always {
    script {
      currentBuild.setDescription("CLI: ${params.cli} - NGINX: ${params.nginx} - PHP: ${params.php}")
    }
  }
}
```

But I would also like to add tag=$(git describe --abbrev=0 --tags) in the build-description.
Unfortunately I cannot execute code in currentBuild.setDescription()

Is there any way I could solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of capturing the output of a command / script into a variable

```
GIT_DESCRIBE = sh (
   script: 'git describe --abbrev=0 --tags',
   returnStdout: true
   ).trim()

   currentBuild.setDescription("Git: ${GIT_DESCRIBE} CLI: ${params.cli} - NGINX: ${params.nginx} - PHP: ${params.php}")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [EnvInject plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin)

It can inject environment variables. Once inserted as an environment variable you can use it in any build step and build job pipelines.